# HTTPS page was not allowed to run insecure content from safari-extension:// URI

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I face a strange behavior in a Safari extension with Safari 9.1 (11601.5.17.1). I try to insert a new Iframe with an src pointing to an html file in the extension package using "safari-extension://...".

The URL is correct and the content is displayed in a new tab, if I click on the link from the error message displayed in the console.

> [blocked] The page at https:// was not allowed to run
>   insecure content from
>   safari-extension://com.mycompany.myextension-7KZE138RQQ/3d4c3273/js/proxy.js.

It seems the URL with safari-extension scheme is not considered as secured and safari applies "no http in https page" security policy.
It used to work before (before what? I don't know.).

Any idea? Could that behavior be changed with a specific Content-security-policy?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because you are using `http` in your iframe `src`. Try changing it to `https` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your safari to display the mixed content,

Follow these steps.

**1. Open up Preferences by selecting "Preferences" from the "Safari" menu.**

**2. Click on the the "Security" (tab) icon near the top of the dialog.**

**3. Make sure that the "Ask before sending a non-secure form to a secure website" option is unchecked.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks David
Actually I identified the problem occurs only when I activate the "Developer" menu. Once it has been activated, my (own) extension will still fail...
The problem does not occur when I reset (manually) Safari and install the extension with an already existing .safariextz package. Until I reactivate the developer menu again...

Looks like a bug or something

Comment: BTW, Safari 9 does not allow anymore to disable this security option.

Comment: Uhh... I was not able to reproduce the problem after a new manual reset. Even after activating the developer menu.

Comment: I had the same problem today... 
Problem was solved after :
1/ Create package from Extension Builder
2/ Uninstall extension (JS) from Extension Builder
3/ Quit safari and install package
4/ Uninstall extension
5/ Restart safari and reinstall extension through Extension Builder
6/ Works fine...

Comment: I've been having the same problem today, but only on a very few domains. (to my knowledge). Works on most http/https pages, but so far I found one https domain where I got same error as the question..

Comment: Not a good answer from a developer perspective.  Users can't be expected to do this to eliminate the problem.

Comment: @FabricioG I'm facing the same problem, development on localhost is very difficult without this feature

Comment: Any other solution for the latest safari ?